# How to change the table header and its content based on admin or normal user login using AJAX and PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a table in which i am changing table header and its content by using PHP session id value but now i want to use AJAX, in which there is button on which a button is clicked and table is requested via JS file and at backend PHP file is executed and that PHP file send the JSON and the JS file parse the table and display the result.

But problem is I cannot use PHP Session in JS file. Please guide how can i proceed to get the changing table header with corresponding row content.

I am attaching part of HTML code with button to call and run server pages and also earlier working using PHP session.

Something need to be done in `viewleadtable.js` file which may get which using is login using PHP Session.

Although table is generated but it is not checking admin is logged in or normal user. Also there is console error for accessing variable `admin`.

Viewing Lead Table

[image: Lead Table]

Viewing Campaign Table

[image]

Following is the part of code `dashboard.html`

```
<section class="operation" id="view_all_lead_Campaign" style="width: 100%;margin: 0 auto; display: none;">
   <!-- Main Tables Campaign and Lead Table                        -->

   <div class="row">

   <!-- MAIN TABLE-->

   <div class="col" >                        
     <button class="viewMainTable" name='viewMainTable' id='viewMainTableButton' >Lead Table</button>
     <button class="viewCampaignTable" name='viewCampaignTable' id='viewCampaignTableButton' >Campaign Table</button>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div id='viewmaintable' style="margin-top: 10px;">

            </div>                        
        </div>                    
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div id="viewcampaigntable" style="margin-top: 10px;">

            </div>                       
        </div>                    
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col span-1-of-3">
            <label></label>                            
        </div>
        <div class="col span-2-of-3">
            <div class="message_box" style="margin-left: 60px;">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</section>
```

In file `viewleadtable.js` But I am trying to use PHP inside it. Also only else part is executing

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var delay = 1000;

    $('#viewMainTableButton').click(function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",

            url: "./server/viewleadtable.php",

            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.message_box').html(
                    '<img src="tenor.gif" width="40" height="40"/>'
                );
            },
            success: function(data) {

                var result = $.parseJSON(data);

                var admin = '<?php echo $_SESSION["Admin"] ?>';
                var user_id = '<?php echo $_SESSION["User_Id"] ?>';


                console.log(result);              


                if(admin == 1){

                    var string = '<table><thead><th>#</th><th>Lead Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Website</th><th>Linkedin</th><th>Lead Description</th><th>Owner Notes</th><th>Admin Notes</th><th>Added By</th><th>Last Contact Date</th><th>Next Contact Date</th><th>Lead Status</th><th>Details</th></thead><tbody>';

                    /* from result create a string of data and append to the div */

                    var i = 1;

                    $.each(result, function(key, value) {

                        string += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + value['Lead_Id'] + "</td><td>" + value['FirstName']+" "+value['LastName'] + "</td><td>" + value['Website'] + "</td><td>" + value['Linkedin'] + "</td><td>" + value['LeadDescription'] + "</td><td>" + value['OwnerNotes'] + "</td><td>" + value['AdminNotes'] + "</td><td>"+ value['LeadAddedBy']+"<br>Date/Time: "+value['LeadAddedOn'] + "</td><td>" + value['LastContactDate'] + "</td><td>" + value['NextContactDate'] + "</td><td>" + value['LeadStatus'] + "</td><td>" + "<a href='#'>Click Here</a></td></tr>";

                        i = i + 1;

                    });

                    string += '</tbody></table>';

                }else{

                    var string = '<table><thead><th>#</th><th>Lead Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Website</th><th>Linkedin</th><th>Lead Description</th><th>Owner Notes</th><th>Last Contact Date</th><th>Next Contact Date</th><th>Lead Status</th><th>Details</th></thead><tbody>';

                    /* from result create a string of data and append to the div */

                    var i = 1;

                    $.each(result, function(key, value) {

                        string += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + value['Lead_Id'] + "</td><td>" + value['FirstName']+" "+value['LastName'] + "</td><td>" + value['Website'] + "</td><td>" + value['Linkedin'] + "</td><td>" + value['LeadDescription'] + "</td><td>" + value['OwnerNotes'] + "</td><td>" + value['LastContactDate'] + "</td><td>" + value['NextContactDate'] + "</td><td>" + value['LeadStatus'] + "</td><td>" + "<a href='#'>Click Here</a></td></tr>";

                        i = i + 1;

                    });

                    string += '</tbody></table>';                    


                }    

                $("#viewmaintable").html(string);
                $('.message_box').html('');

            }

        });       

    });

});
```

In `viewleadtable.php`

```
<?php 

// send a JSON encoded array to client

include('connection.php');

$selectSQL = "SELECT * FROM tbl_main_lead_info ";

$result_array = array();

$result = $conn -> query ($selectSQL);

// If there are results from database push to result array

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

        array_push($result_array, $row);

    }

}

echo json_encode($result_array);

$conn->close();

?>
```

Similarly I have code for viewing campaign Table also but the Problem is i am not able to execute the if else condition using PHP Session variable.

In Short below thing needs to be modified as it is not working.

```
success: function(data) {

                var result = $.parseJSON(data);

                var admin = '<?php echo $_SESSION["Admin"] ?>';
                var user_id = '<?php echo $_SESSION["User_Id"] ?>';


                console.log(result);              


                if(admin == 1){

                    var string = '<table><thead><th>#</th><th>Lead Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Website</th><th>Linkedin</th><th>Lead Description</th><th>Owner Notes</th><th>Admin Notes</th><th>Added By</th><th>Last Contact Date</th><th>Next Contact Date</th><th>Lead Status</th><th>Details</th></thead><tbody>';

                    /* from result create a string of data and append to the div */

                    var i = 1;

                    $.each(result, function(key, value) {

                        string += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + value['Lead_Id'] + "</td><td>" + value['FirstName']+" "+value['LastName'] + "</td><td>" + value['Website'] + "</td><td>" + value['Linkedin'] + "</td><td>" + value['LeadDescription'] + "</td><td>" + value['OwnerNotes'] + "</td><td>" + value['AdminNotes'] + "</td><td>"+ value['LeadAddedBy']+"<br>Date/Time: "+value['LeadAddedOn'] + "</td><td>" + value['LastContactDate'] + "</td><td>" + value['NextContactDate'] + "</td><td>" + value['LeadStatus'] + "</td><td>" + "<a href='#'>Click Here</a></td></tr>";

                        i = i + 1;

                    });

                    string += '</tbody></table>';

                }else{

                    var string = '<table><thead><th>#</th><th>Lead Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Website</th><th>Linkedin</th><th>Lead Description</th><th>Owner Notes</th><th>Last Contact Date</th><th>Next Contact Date</th><th>Lead Status</th><th>Details</th></thead><tbody>';

                    /* from result create a string of data and append to the div */

                    var i = 1;

                    $.each(result, function(key, value) {

                        string += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + value['Lead_Id'] + "</td><td>" + value['FirstName']+" "+value['LastName'] + "</td><td>" + value['Website'] + "</td><td>" + value['Linkedin'] + "</td><td>" + value['LeadDescription'] + "</td><td>" + value['OwnerNotes'] + "</td><td>" + value['LastContactDate'] + "</td><td>" + value['NextContactDate'] + "</td><td>" + value['LeadStatus'] + "</td><td>" + "<a href='#'>Click Here</a></td></tr>";

                        i = i + 1;

                    });
```

Comment: can i use this `var admin = <?php echo $_SESSION['Admin'] ?>;
                var user_id = <?php echo $_SESSION['User_Id'] ?>;` to check for admin or normal user in my javascript file

Comment: I would add a role column in database user table and store user roles in sessions on login page, then check if user is and admin or normal, with an if statement. I see you have role for admin set to 1. check with that.

Comment: yes i added that by using column Admin and values for it are 1 and 0 for each registered user

Comment: So ? it should work right ?

Comment: but it is not working in JS file as i cannot use PHP Session variable in Javascript function, I updated my post question please see

Comment: 1.You can use if statements in jquery ajax too, same as you do in php. 2. can you just put part of the codes where you want to use it, its hard to read your codes.

Comment: or could you extend discussion to chat

Comment: @Dilek I updated the code please see it

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment you can use php in ajax or u can use if statements in ajax.

This should work :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var delay = 1000;
    $('#viewMainTableButton').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "./server/viewleadtable.php",
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('.message_box').html(
                    '<img src="tenor.gif" width="40" height="40"/>'
                );
            },
            success: function(data) {
                var result = $.parseJSON(data);
            /*Delete this variables if you dont need*/
                var admin = '<?php echo $_SESSION["Admin"] ?>';
                var user_id = '<?php echo $_SESSION["User_Id"] ?>';
                console.log(result);              
               <?php if($_SESSION["Admin"] == 1){ ?>
                    var string = '<table><thead><th>#</th><th>Lead Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Website</th><th>Linkedin</th><th>Lead Description</th><th>Owner Notes</th><th>Admin Notes</th><th>Added By</th><th>Last Contact Date</th><th>Next Contact Date</th><th>Lead Status</th><th>Details</th></thead><tbody>';
                    /* from result create a string of data and append to the div */
                    var i = 1;
                    $.each(result, function(key, value) {
                        string += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + value['Lead_Id'] + "</td><td>" + value['FirstName']+" "+value['LastName'] + "</td><td>" + value['Website'] + "</td><td>" + value['Linkedin'] + "</td><td>" + value['LeadDescription'] + "</td><td>" + value['OwnerNotes'] + "</td><td>" + value['AdminNotes'] + "</td><td>"+ value['LeadAddedBy']+"<br>Date/Time: "+value['LeadAddedOn'] + "</td><td>" + value['LastContactDate'] + "</td><td>" + value['NextContactDate'] + "</td><td>" + value['LeadStatus'] + "</td><td>" + "<a href='#'>Click Here</a></td></tr>";
                        i = i + 1;
                    });
                    string += '</tbody></table>';
                <?php }else{ ?>
                    var string = '<table><thead><th>#</th><th>Lead Id</th><th>Name</th><th>Website</th><th>Linkedin</th><th>Lead Description</th><th>Owner Notes</th><th>Last Contact Date</th><th>Next Contact Date</th><th>Lead Status</th><th>Details</th></thead><tbody>';
                    /* from result create a string of data and append to the div */
                    var i = 1;
                    $.each(result, function(key, value) {
                        string += "<tr><td>" + i + "</td><td>" + value['Lead_Id'] + "</td><td>" + value['FirstName']+" "+value['LastName'] + "</td><td>" + value['Website'] + "</td><td>" + value['Linkedin'] + "</td><td>" + value['LeadDescription'] + "</td><td>" + value['OwnerNotes'] + "</td><td>" + value['LastContactDate'] + "</td><td>" + value['NextContactDate'] + "</td><td>" + value['LeadStatus'] + "</td><td>" + "<a href='#'>Click Here</a></td></tr>";
                        i = i + 1;
                    });
                    string += '</tbody></table>';                    
               <?php } ?>   
                $("#viewmaintable").html(string);
                $('.message_box').html('');
            }
        });       
    });
});
```

Or you can do like this check for user role not for admin.

```
var user = <?php echo $_SESSION["role"]; ?>;

    if (user === 1) {
      //Write your ajax codes here 
    } else {
      //Write your ajax codes here 
    }
```

Comment: This `<?php if($_SESSION["Admin"] == 1){ ?>` cannot be used

Comment: @RINKUYADAV see updated answer with ajax, your user role should be stored in sessions before using them. and first example is working fine, when I try it with ajax post method to change url in my own form.

Comment: I think i solved by making each lead and campaign button as FORM submit and then passing session variable with input type hidden

Comment: @RINKUYADAV well you could do that with a hidden input to send admin role to ajax and check with if statement, tought you w'not want to use form in datatable, anyway glad u solved